# Upper bound with recursion tree

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, upperbound

I need to find asymptotic upper bound using recursion tree. 
The relation is **T(n) = T(n-1) + 1/n**
I suppose that it is O(logn) but i cannot show it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: take a look at the [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).